# Linux Questions: to close/migrate or to accept

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raspberry Pi itself vs. specific OS issues](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/raspberry-pi-itself-vs-specific-os-issues)

It's apparent already that there are going to be a lot of questions relating to basic setup and accomplishing certain tasks within Linux.  A choice we're going to have to make is whether to close/migrate these questions or to accept them as part of the community.  Traditionally I believe that SE sites should be for *experts*, however this site as a resource is sort of a unique one in that experts in some areas relevant to the Raspberry Pi might be newbies in other areas.

## Reasons not to accept these questions

- They could be considered off-topic for this site
- They have already been answered on another SE site
- They do not necessarily relate to "experts"

## Reasons to accept these questions

- Many questions considered simple in another community may be key ideas necessary for new Raspberry Pi users (especially since the images are fairly bare-bones)
- Questions that initially appear to be linux-specific may have a useful answer relevant to the Raspberry Pi device itself
- It increases the likelihood that a Raspberry Pi user searching this site will be able to find an answer to his or her question (though this can be solved with migration)

It's important, however, to decide early how to treat this to make sure the community is shaped in a useful direction.  Hopefully some folks with greater insight for the SE network as a whole can weigh in.