# What questions should be protected, community questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

What questions should be made protected, community questions? Post your proposals as answers. The rules are.

1. A proposal shall be voted on for **one week.**
2. After one week the proposal shall be evaluated.
3. If the proposal has more upvotes than downvotes the proposed question shall
    be made protected and community wiki.

**Remember! Your votes are what decides if a proposal succeeds or fails. So use the standard voting buttons to vote on a proposal!**

> Meta Discussion: [Are some off-topic questions necessary for a healthy community?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/153/46)

Comment: Proposals should perhaps be based on questions that we can see being frequently duplicated. More will be revealed when we go public tomorrow.

Comment: I don't really feel this is worth a full answer, but something like "how do I install debian?" or something similar seems an obvious one.

Answer (score 8):

Can we hold off and throttle back these "solutions" looking for a problem?

This is going to be a great community, but there seems to be an over exuberance of policy-making and procedures to micromanage problems that you haven't even encountered, yet.

You shouldn't be actively seeking out an author's contributions to usurp them under 'community wiki' … nor should you be restricting replies to posts as 'protected' if there isn't a problem. Community Wiki has [been somewhat deprecated](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) — 'Protected' questions prevent answers by anonymous and very new users. These tools are there to solve very *specific* problems **when they arise**, but actively seeking out questions to apply these tools starts to feel like a hammer looking for a nail.

I've been really happy with the progress and potential of this site, and I'm sure these suggestions are offered under the best of intentions. But you've been in private beta for only six days and are, just now, about to go public. Let's not be too eager to set up a labyrinth of behavioral mores that will only make this place feel somewhat intimidating and foreboding.

I read Shog's post in response to [force-feeding off-topic questions](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/are-some-off-topic-questions-necessary-for-a-healthy-community), and I think the closing paragraph(s) are of particular importance:

> ### In closing: don't get too distracted by FAQs and references
>
> I'm glad to see that you're all thinking about this stuff already, but don't spend too much time on it up front. The meat & potatoes of any Stack Exchange site are ordinary questions and answers; "canonical" answers to generalized questions, collaborative wiki answers, and extensive tag wikis are all great tools to have, but under normal circumstances they'll constitute a tiny fraction of the site's total content. Create them as-needed, but don't let them get in the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'll get the ball rolling with:

[How do I connect/disconnect a flash drive from the command line?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/389/how-do-i-connect-disconnect-a-flash-drive-from-the-command-line/)

This is something I'm sure we shall see a lot. And although not related to the RPi, the lack of storage provided by the SD card will be an issue for many.

Answer (score 1):

I would put this question

[How can I protect against intrusion and malware before connecting it to the internet (especially on a public IP address)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/508/how-can-i-protect-against-intrusion-and-malware-before-connecting-it-to-the-inte)

at the top of my list.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much everything on this thread (which includes @Jivings suggestion):

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-should-i-do-first-to-ensure-my-rpi-runs-efficiently-safely-and-securely

It could be better worded/etc,  but this and its contents just smack of an FAQ or easy-to-find protected community/wiki questions.