# Community Wiki suggestions: Wi Fi Dongles, Emulators?

Tags: discussion

What is the best way to suggest a community wiki?

I think a canonical "Definitive list of emulators" post would be useful (like the [Operating systems post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/534/definitive-list-of-operating-systems)), but I don't want to put it out there unless the community thinks its a good idea.

Other good community wiki posts:
Known working wifi dongles?  Followup to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/123/should-all-linux-compatible-usb-bluetooth-wi-fi-devices-work).

Answer (score 3):

The conclusion was reached that CW should be used sparingly.

See this meta question and the top voted answer for more information:

[What questions should be protected, community questions?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/what-questions-should-be-protected-community-questions)

Community wiki automatically occurs when an answer or question is edited enough times and thus is a real contribution from the community. I don't feel that questions should need to be made artificially community wiki, except in certain specific circumstances. Such as the [Operating Systems question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/534/definitive-list-of-operating-systems), which would be better off being kept as up to date as possible.

Comment: I'm with you, but it seems like both of those questions are useful, but will require a lot of community support as emulation support and wireless drivers improve over time.  I'd rather look at one emulation post instead of seeing a question about Atari, followed by Game Boy, followed by Playstation, followed by SCUMMVM, followed by Nintendo, followed by Super Nintendo, etc.  If we're looking to inflate the number of posts here, avoiding an emulation community wiki is a big step towards it.  Same goes for the "does this dongle work? posts.

Comment: @Zoot This is what tag wikis are for. Feel free to write a list of FAQ under the emulation tag.