# Dealing with overlap

Tags: discussion, scope

> Related: [Raspberry Pi itself vs. specific OS issues](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/raspberry-pi-itself-vs-specific-os-issues)

It seems that you guys have a sizeable overlap with [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). Basically, a large chunk of software questions for RPi are on-topic on the other site as well. Migrating all of them may result on your site becoming much less active, questions-wise.

To be clear, by "overlap" I'm talking about questions and topics which are on-topic on both sites.

So, how do you plan on dealing with this?

Answer (score 4):

We are in danger of migrating every question about software. The whole point of the Linux kernel is to abstract away the hardware, and therefore, no question about software is necessarily about the Pi. If questions are asked here and are applicable to a significant proportion of Pi users, then we should keep them here.

Comment: After all, if all questions are migrated away, there won't be enough questions to sustain this site, so it won't be there for RaspberryPi users at all.

Answer (score 3):

I've been thinking about this issue and I have to agree with Alex Chamberlain for the most part. We should take a stance similar to [Ask Ubuntu][1].

**Ask Ubuntu FAQ**

> We welcome questions about:
>
> - Using and administering Ubuntu, including official Ubuntu derivatives.
> - Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
> - Development on Ubuntu.
> - Services provided by Ubuntu
> - Any question not mentioned below or here are great! There are no "dumb"
>     questions!
>
> This is not the right place for:
>
> - Linux Mint, Backtrack, and other Linux distributions (try our friends at
>     Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).
> - Bug reports (How do I submit a bug?).
> - Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) (More information about
>     Alpha and Beta release issues).
> - Shopping Recommendations

**Basically if your question is about or happens on the Raspberry Pi it is on topic.**

Comment: OT: Isn't Mint a Ubuntu derivative?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Haha. I have no clue. I'm assuming they say that because even still it differs from Ubuntu and certain stuff isn't the same.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Mint is a third-party Ubuntu derivative. Ask Ubuntu only deals with [**official** Ubuntu derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives).

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Self-answered so that the objective question and my subjective views are kept separate for voting. Feel free to put forward your own views in answers</sup>

On chem.SE we deal with overlaps (with Physics and Bio) in the following manner. It looks like it could address the situation here as well.

- If one can *clearly* determine which audience the question is geared towards, then migrate if necessary.
- If not, then keep the question on the site where it was asked. It's on-topic there, you need not worry about "it has a better chance of getting an answer". As long as it gets an answer, it's fine. [The presence or absence of another SE site on a particular topic has no bearing on whether a question on that topic is appropriate here or not](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21827/addition-of-a-neutral-electrolyte-to-water-how-can-it-increase-conductivity#comment50482_21827).
- If the question does not get an answer within X days, and the question isn't a crap question ("[Don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96823/whats-the-deal-with-migrating-css-questions-to-webmasters/96825#96825)" is one of the rules of migration), *then* migrate it, asking the OP first if he's OK with it.

Note that you may want to discuss this with U&L community members as well.